# react/webpack/php

Tags: php, reactjs, webpack

Написал я приложение на react, которое взаимодействует с базой MySQL через php. Проект создавал через webpack npm create-react-app. На локальном сервере все работает отлично, но после окончательной сборки через npm run build, в папке build я не нахожу php скрипты, и приложение, естественно, на хостинге не работает. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Наверное потому что `ReactJS` работает на `NodeJS`, а не на `PHP`

Comment: Дело в том, что само приложение осталось рабочим, просто перестало подтягивать информацию с базы в виду отсутствия php скриптов, которые пропали после сборки в продакшен из папки build. Вопрос в том, что webpack делает с php скриптами после сборки?

Answer (score 0):

это не прямой ответ и возможно автор уже нашел решение, но для имеющих похожую проблему попробую немного описать. при формировании вебпак делает то что в нем настроено и в первую очередь как и следует из наименования, он упаковывает скрипты ноды. но так же и копирует в конечную точку как результат своей работы, так и все что есть в каталоге public, если это настроено. если ничего не изменено в create-react-app, то именно так и происходит. и в каталог build копируются не только php скрипты, но и картинки и прочее что лежит в описанном исходном месте. таким образом, если надо ч то-то изменить в этих файлах, то меняется исходное, а в конечное оно потом будет скопировано. и вторая часть - все что будет сделано в конечной точке, после компиляции будет замещено тем что в исходной. но это не мешает производить замену как тех, так и других файлов, не относящихся к коду ноды без компиляции. при этом во время копирования в конечное место надо учитывать права на файлы и если у скопировавшего прав больше, то вебпак не сможет произвести свои действия, о чем сообщит.
в общем прочтение документации по работе вебпака и компиляции create-react-app поможет возможно больше чем мое скромное поверхностное описание. целью данного сообщения ставлю общее ознакомление с происходящими процессами, что возможно поможет избежать описанных ситуаций или воспользоваться ими правильно.